# Why are my new-line characters '\n' being removed from my csv file at download?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am writing this function to take a list of objects and then convert them to a csv file.
I generate the column row, and then the subsequent data rows.

Everything looks great when I print the 'cvsStr' to the JS console in Firefox and MS edge.  I copy and past the ouput to a simple text file and then open in MS Excel.  Everything looks about right.

However when I attempt to serve 'csvStr' via a downloadable csv file.....it appears that all of the return characters have been stripped out and it all becomes just a complete mess.

What am I missing here ?  Any help that could be provided would be greatly appreciated!!!  Thanks in advance!!!!

````
    let val:string='';
    let valList = [] ;
    let valStr:string = '';
    let keysItr = Object.keys(this.policies[0]);
    let keyList = Array.from(keysItr);
    let keyStr = keyList.toString() ;
    keyStr = keyStr.trim() ;
    keyStr = keyStr.concat('\n');

    for(var i = 0 ; i < this.policies.length ; i++ ){

      for (let key of Object.keys(this.policies[i])) {

        val = this.policies[i][key] ;
        if(val == null){
          val = '';
        }
        val = val.toString() ;
        val = val.replace('$','');
        val = val.replace(',','');
        valList.push(val);
        //console.log(val);
      }
      valStr = valStr.concat(valList.toString());
      valStr = valStr.trim() ;
      valStr = valStr.concat('\n');
      valList = [] ;

    }
    let csvStr = keyStr.concat(valStr);

    csvStr = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,'.concat(csvStr);
    console.log(csvStr);

    let data = encodeURI(csvStr) ;
    let link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', data);
    link.setAttribute('download', 'FOOBAR');
    link.click() ;

  }// end of getCsv()```
````

Comment: I'd try url-encoding that string

Comment: Thanks Bergi for setting me on the correct track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.... Replaced this block of code

```
let link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', data);
link.setAttribute('download', 'FOOBAR');
link.click() ;
```

With this:

```
let csvStr = keyStr.concat(valStr);

var element = document.createElement('a');
element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' +encodeURIComponent(csvStr));
element.setAttribute('download', 'FOOBAR.csv');

element.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(element);

element.click();

document.body.removeChild(element);
```